# How do I access data attribute of elements with the same class name?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div class="range" data-max="100">0-100</li>
<div class="range" data-max="200">0-200</li>
<div class="range" data-max="300">0-300</li>
```

I wish to access data-max in my javascript. For example, if I click 0-200, I get 200 only.
Here is my javascript.

```
const ranges = document.querySelectorAll(".range");
for(var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++){
    ranges[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        console.log(this.dataset.max);
    });
}
```

The output when I click 0-200 is

> 200 100

I'm expecting 200.

Here are my questions:
1. how to get expected value---200 as in  the example.
2. What is the scope of this in this.dataset.max in my code? I thought its scope is the function.
3. When I change this to ranges[i], it seems ranges[i] is undefined. why?

> guessNum.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataset' of undefined

I'm expecting answers in pure javascript. No jquery pls.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Invalid HTML always does weird stufff.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well your html is invalid, if you fix it it will work.
What is happening is the divs become nested inside each other and the click events bubble up the divs.

```js
const ranges = document.querySelectorAll(".range");
for(var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++){
    ranges[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        console.log(this.dataset.max);
    });
}
```

```html
<div class="range" data-max="100">0-100</div>
<div class="range" data-max="200">0-200</div>
<div class="range" data-max="300">0-300</div>
```

Comment: Great I learned an interesting piece of code, useful so much.

Answer (score 0):

Please avoid asking multiple questions, and please don't change the question to something entirely different. The original should have been closed as it was a simple typo, and the additional questions are duplicates.

> 1. What is the scope of this in this.dataset.max in my code? I thought its scope is the function.

*this* is always scoped to the current execution context. However, it's set in a number of ways, mostly in the call. Arrow functions adopt the *this* of their outer context, which is arguably how it's set, not how it's scoped.

Where a listener is added using *addEventListener*, then *this* within the function references the element on which the listener was placed. That isn't about scope, it's how *this* is set within the function.

See [*How does the “this” keyword work?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

> 2. When I change this to ranges[i], it seems ranges[i] is undefined. why?

Because *i* within the listeners has a closure to the original *i*, which has been incremented to *ranges.length* and hence references a non-existent element of the collection. See [*JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example).

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for my mistakes.

Comment: @AbelZhu—you seem new here so that's OK. ;-) Just make sure your title and question match.